# Glass edges look blurred

Tags: modeling, glass

I'm modeling an interior. As you can see, a part of the table's glass top looks blurred. I think this is given by the noise due to the engine lacking data to understand how to render the transarency of glass.
Here is a detail of my problem and the the nodes of the glass material.
Any advices for "sharpening" the edges of the top?
[image: Blurred glass]

[image: Glass material nodes]

Comment: Why are you using a simulated glass shader? I don't think it is actually blurred, just the appearance of the glossy/transparent mix. Have you tried using just a Glass Shader instead - that would include refraction which would make it look far more realistic (or try replacing your Transparent shader with a Refraction shader)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the "blurred" part is mostly volume shader, surface is tranparent.
If you don't want to change your shader, you can try to use a bevel on the edges to catch the light and make it look real somehow.